# what does this sword sign on folder means?

Tags: windows, working-directory

There is a sword sign on one of my folder. What does this mean?

[image]

Comment: That's not a sword, [it's an exclamation mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclamation_mark) `!`, aka a "bang".

Comment: https://www.distractify.com/p/save-icon-vending-machine ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an icon overlay added by TortoiseSVN or TortoiseGit to indicate the folder contains files that have been modified but not yet committed.

### TortoiseSVN

[TortoiseSVN's website has a page listing the different icons](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html)

[image]

### TortoiseGit

[TortoiseGit's website has a page listing the different icons](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-wcstatus.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These overlay icons lets you know the status of individual files under their version control mechanism. A green tick is expected to make sure that files are upto date, but any other icon marks are too ok. The icons depend on your behavior of editing the files.

You should normally see a corresponding `.git` or `.svn` folder in the root directory. Anything else is likely to have a one of the icon (eg. modified, added, etc. including non-versioned marking).